# Explain this DSP notation

Tags: audio, filter, signal-processing, pseudocode

I'm trying to implement [this extenstion](http://www.dsprelated.com/dspbooks/pasp/Extended_Karplus_Strong_Algorithm.html) of the Karplus-Strong plucked string algorithm, but I don't understand the notation there used. Maybe it will take years of study, but maybe it won't - maybe you can tell me.

I think the equations below are in the frequency domain or something. Just starting with the first equation, H<sub>p</sub>(z), the pick direction lowpass filter. For one direction you use p = 0, for the other, perhaps 0.9. This boils down to to 1 in the first case, or 0.1 / (1 - 0.9 z<sup>-1</sup>) in the second.

[alt text http://www.dsprelated.com/josimages/pasp/img902.png](http://www.dsprelated.com/josimages/pasp/img902.png)

Now, I feel like this might mean, in coding terms, something towards:

```
H_p(float* input, int time) {
  if (downpick) {
    return input[time];
  } else {
    return some_function_of(input[t], input[t-1]);
  }
}
```

Can someone give me a hint? Or is this futile and I really need all the DSP background to implement this? I was a mathematician once...but this ain't my domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the z<sup>-1</sup> just means a one-unit delay.

Let's take H<sub>p</sub> = (1-p)/(1-pz<sup>-1</sup>).

If we follow the convention of "x" for input and "y" for output, the transfer function H = y/x (=output/input)

so we get y/x = (1-p)/(1-pz<sup>-1</sup>)

or (1-p)x = (1-pz<sup>-1</sup>)y

(1-p)x[n] = y[n] - py[n-1]

or: **y[n] = py[n-1] + (1-p)x[n]**

In C code this can be implemented

```
y += (1-p)*(x-y);
```

without any additional state beyond using the output "y" as a state variable itself. Or you can go for the more literal approach:

```
y_delayed_1 = y;
y = p*y_delayed_1 + (1-p)*x;
```

As far as the other equations go, they're all typical equations except for that second equation which looks like maybe it's a way of selecting either H<sub>Β</sub> = 1-z<sup>-1</sup> OR 1-z<sup>-2</sup>. (what's N?)

The filters are kind of vague and they'll be tougher for you to deal with unless you can find some prepackaged filters. In general they're of the form

H = H0*(1+az<sup>-1</sup>+bz<sup>-2</sup>+cz<sup>-3</sup>...)/(1+rz<sup>-1</sup>+sz<sup>-2</sup>+tz<sup>-3</sup>...)

and all you do is write down H = y/x, cross multiply to get

H0 * (1+az<sup>-1</sup>+bz<sup>-2</sup>+cz<sup>-3</sup>...) * x = (1+rz<sup>-1</sup>+sz<sup>-2</sup>+tz<sup>-3</sup>...) * y

and then isolate "y" by itself, making the output "y" a linear function of various delays of itself and of the input.

But *designing* filters (picking the a,b,c,etc.) is tougher than implementing them, for the most part.

Comment: BTW to answer your question, N is the period of the string vibration being modeled, in samples.